# Cannot perform command as a different User - even from root user

Tags: linux, permissions, node.js, sudo, syslog

I have pm2 node modules installed in a user called `otheruser`. I need to run the program from `root` user.

If I normally logged to `otheruser` and perform any action its working fine.

```
otheruser@bubble-server:~$ /home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/pm2 list
● Agent online - public key: xxxxxxxx - machine name: server - Web access: https://app.keymetrics.io/
┌────────────────┬────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ App name       │ id │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ watching │
├────────────────┼────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│                                                                                            │
└────────────────┴────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────────┘
```

But if I logged in as root or anyother user other than otheruser its not working.

```
root@server:~# su -s /bin/bash -c "/home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/pm2 list" otheruser
root@server:~#
```

Its giving the following in the syslog

```
server node[25227]: No AX.25 port data configured
```

Comment: try adding `-l` to the command, e.g. `su -l -s /bin/bash -c "/home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/pm2 list" otheruser`, and see if it works.

Comment: @mforsetti This gives ``` /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory```

Comment: Found it, the below answer helped and fixed my issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35600265/7485670